# Spring autowired dependency is null in class being tested

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm trying to write a unit test for my PersonController class, which uses a dependency `org.modelmapper.ModelMapper`. The problem is that when the test calls a method of PersonController that uses the ModelMapper, the ModelMapper is null which results in an error. Clearly it is not being autowired correctly when running the test, but it works when running the application. I am hoping there is a way to fix this problem without needing to add the ModelMapper as a constructor parameter.

The code snippets are shown below:

```
@SpringBootTest

class PersonControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private IPersonService personService;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonController underTest;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        underTest = new PersonController(personService);
    }

    ...Tests...
}
```

And the relevant PersonController code is:

```
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper _modelMapper;

    private final IPersonService _personService;

    public PersonController (IPersonService personService) {
        _personService = personService;
    }

    ...Code that calls _modelMapper...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should annotate your class PersonControllerTest with

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class PersonControllerTest {
```

or

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PersonControllerTest {
```

depending on your use case. This should already fix your problem. If you are still using Junit4 you should use

```
@RunWith(Springrunner.class)
class PersonControllerTest {
```

but since you are using

```
@BeforeEach
```

that should not be the case :)

EDIT:

When you use ModelMapper via @Autowired you have to use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) . You also have to annotate your class with @SpringBootTest or import the classes that should be available via dependency Injection manually using the @Import annotation.

Comment: Unfortunately after trying @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) and @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) I still have the same problem where underTest._modelMapper is null. I've also tried removing the @SpringBootTest with no luck as suggested by another answer.

Comment: I eddited my answer. The @SpringBootTest annotation should help :)

Comment: This makes the ModelMapper available to my test class if I have an @Autowired ModelMapper in it but it is still null in the PersonController

Comment: so 50% done ? ;) Why would you not also use @Autowired for your PersonController ? I am not 100% sure but I don´t think constructor dependency Injection works in TestClasses. There is however no reason not to use Autowired since all the downsides of Autowired are irrelevant in uni-tests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it did fix my problem with the ModelMapper being null but also caused the actual PersonService implementation to be used instead of the Mockito mock.

Comment: If you want your PsersonService also to be a mock you cannotate it with MockBean for Spring integration test if you are using ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) or annotationg it with Mock for @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class). Your example however then does not show a class that will actually be tested where the InjectMocks should be called

Comment: It turns out the problem with the PersonService was that it was marked as final in the PersonController. Final solution has ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) and SpringBootTest on the Test class, with InjectMocks and Autowired on its PersonController. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. be carefull with mixing Mockito and Spring Boot tests. You can run into weird scenarios. I personally try to use one or another, but i guess that is a matter of opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

One problem here is that you are creating a controller class manually using `new PersonController(personService)` so spring annotation `@Autowired` does not have any effect here (because spring is not creating the class is not configuring it).

Another issue is that you are using mockito `@InjectMocks` which basically injects mocks (for the unit test) but at the same time, you are using `@SpringBootTest` which is for integration test (application is started as normal but in test mode).

Based on your description is not clear to me if you are trying to code a unit test or an integration test. so:

1. If you are coding a unit test, remove `@SpringBootTest` add `ModelMapper` as a constructor parameter and instantiate a class with two mocks.
2. If you are coding an [spring integration test](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), remove `@InjectMocks` and manual class instantiation of class and flag controller as  `@Autowire` in test.

Comment: I'm trying to code a unit test, but I wanted to avoid passing the model mapper as a parameter in the constructor since its not something I would mock.